# Copying file to a server that is not part of a domain

Tags: c#, .net

I have a wpf application (C#) that needs to copy a file to a server that is not part of a domain. FTP cannot be used. I looked into using LogonUser() within advapi32.dll but could impersonate the local user to the machine successfully. Are there any other options?

Comment: The problem with mapping a drive, is you need to supply the user name and password each time you log into the machine that is running the application

Comment: Did you try [WNetAddConnection(2|3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385418(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to impersonate the local user by setting logonProvider to 0 and logonType to 9 using advapi32.dll.

Answer (score 1):

one option is there to upload file through WCF Service..in that case it is not required that it should be in same domain.

Here article's title is large file upload / download but it is meant only for small files upto
[10 MB - 40 MB].

[WCF File Upload Download](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFDownloadUploadService.aspx)

[Second Option](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html)

Comment: This is much-much more complicated solution that simple file copy.

Comment: Yes, I agree, why so difficut to sort out?

Answer (score 0):

One is to open the security on the machine you are copying to, such that none authenticated users are aloowed to write to disk.

Another is to create a local user on the machine that you are writing to , that has the same name and password as the domain account making the call. This works in some situations.

Comment: The first is not an option, i have tried the second but the user fails to login, even though user and password are the same, shame!